# XML Schema restriction

Tags: xsd

I need a schema restriction satisfying the following conditions:

- List of locations, prefixed by + or – and separated by a space character

  Ex: +Z*1 +FR –PAR

Possible location types:

- Area: Z*1,Z*2, Z*3
- ATPCo Zone: 3 numerics
- Country: 2 alphanums
- City: 3 alphanums
- State/province: 2 alphas/2 alphas
- Region: 5 alphas or 4 alpha + 1 num from 1 to 5
- IATA subarea: 2 numerics

Answer (score 0):

The xsd list type allows for spaces seperated items.  The following will allow all words:

```
<simpleType name='locations'>
   <list itemType='string'/>
</simpleType>
```

You could use a regular expression to restrict all strings to starting with + or -

```
 <simpleType name='location'>
    <restriction base='string'>
        <pattern value='[\+\-]\w'/>
    </restriction>
 </simpleType>

 <simpleType name='locations'>
    <list itemType='location'/>
 </simpleType>
```